# LocaleResolver in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I am using session locale resolver for my application. I am showing the languages in dropdown. if the user selects on any of the language then repopulates all values from that language.

```
<property name="interceptors">
    <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </list>
</property>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="languageCode" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" />
```

But its is not reading it from the session. Always it considers the defaultlanguage from browser setting.
Please help on this.

Comment: How do you check that the local is set in the session (or not)?

Comment: When the user selects a new locale and submits the page are you adding the correct request parameter to the URL? In your case you have specified a paramName of languageCode. So the request URL should be something like http://mysite.com/myPage?languageCode=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to obtain the locale in this way:

```
Locale loc=RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request);
```

Comment: If the controller method is annotated with @RequestMapping, you can just add a Locale parameter to the method and Spring will automatically provide it for you. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments

Comment: @Kevin Stembridge: I would only make the statement, that it is a bed idea to obtain the locale direct from the session. -- And of course the parameter way is even much better thant what I have writen.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring 4.0 we can Also use `LocaleContextResolver.getLocale()` method as well.